# Bind Icon depending on Enum in WPF Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf

I have at treeview TextBox, and I want convert my Enum:

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag}" />

public enum AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag
    {
        NotReady = 0,
        Ready = 1,
        AcceptedByAdmin=2
    }
```

to Icons. There will be 3 icons, let say ready.jpg, notready.jpg and AcceptedByAdmin.jpg

Country and Region has pool AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag and on both I want to display this enum/Icon

```
            <TreeView Name="structureTree" SelectedItemChanged="structureTree_SelectedItemChanged" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="413" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Width="Auto" PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="structureTree_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="12">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ServiceMy:Country}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfRegions}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text=" H:"/>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfHotels}"/>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text=" "/>
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text=" FG:"/>
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag}" />
                <!--<Button Name="BTNAddRegion" Height="20" Content="+" Click="BTNAddRegion_Click"></Button>-->
            </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ServiceMy:Region}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfProvinces}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text=" H:"/>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfHotels}"/>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text=" "/>
                <!--<Button Name="BTNAddProvince" Height="20" Content="+" Click="BTNAddProvince_Click"></Button>-->
            </StackPanel>


                    </DataTemplate>

                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
        </GroupBox>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: For solution without converter see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787725/how-to-display-different-enum-icons-using-xaml-only/41150128#41150128

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Create a [Value Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

It takes your enum value and returns the filename of the appropriate icon.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag), typeof(string))]
public class AcceptationStatusGlobalFlagToIconFilenameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch ((AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag)value)
        {
            case AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag.Ready:
                return "ready.jpg";
            case AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag.NotReady:
                return "notready.jpg";
            case AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag.AcceptedByAdmin:
                return "AcceptedByAdmin.jpg";
            default:
                return null;
        }

        // or
        return Enum.GetName(typeof(AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag), value) + ".jpg";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You will need to add a reference to this converter in your XAML

```
<Window ... xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:App.Converters" ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:AcceptationStatusGlobalFlagToIconFilenameConverter x:Key="IconConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Replace your TextBlock

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag}" />
```

with an Image and tell it use your converter

```
<Image Source="{Binding AcceptationStatusGlobalFlag, Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: What should you do if the graphic is a scalable shape defined in a XAML resource, not a bitmap in a file?

Comment: @Anthony you should create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy solution to this, is to use a value convertor; so create an IValueConverter implementation that converts your enums to the corresponding images.

For more information see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use Binding with value converter: http://blogs.msdn.com/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx