# How to display different Enum icons using XAML only?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, enums

I want to show a different icon/image depending on an enum value. For example, if I had the following enum:

```
  public enum UploadStatus
  {
      Unknown = 0,
      WaitingToUpload = 10,
      Uploading = 20,
      Uploaded = 30,
      UploadFailed = 40
  }
```

I'd like to write XAML that looks something like this:

```
...

<EnumImage Value="{Binding Path=CurrentStatus}">
  <EnumImageItem Value="Unknown"         Image="/images/unknown.png" />
  <EnumImageItem Value="WaitingToUpload" Image="/images/clock.png" />
  <EnumImageItem Value="Uploading"       Image="/images/upload.png" />
  <EnumImageItem Value="Uploaded"        Image="/images/tick.png" />
  <EnumImageItem Value="UploadFailed"    Image="/images/error.png" />
</EnumImage>

...
```

I've found many posts suggesting custom **IValueConverters**, but those solutions don't fit the XAML paradigm.

Any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: In what way does a value convert not "fit the XAML paradigm"?

Comment: Well, I believe the image paths should remain in the XAML, not in C# code.  In the IValueConverter solutions I've seem, the converter is responsible for mapping the enum value to an image path.  I see more benefits in keeping it all in XAML.

Comment: ValueConverter exists for exactly this reason.  It was meant to take a data type and convert for the view.

Comment: @Stephan: True, however it should be possible to declare the relationship mapping in Xaml whilst using a converter to "execute" the mapping.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones I totally agree, but that doesn't change the fact that he's likely going to need a ValueConverter no matter what he tries.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a Value converter which maintains the "XAML paradigm" that is the relationship between enum values and images is maintained in XAML.

```
[ContentProperty("Items")]
public class EnumToObjectConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ResourceDictionary Items { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string key = Enum.GetName(value.GetType(), value);
        return Items[key];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This converter only works for one way binding");
    }
}
```

Note that this is very generic it actually maps values of any enum type to any arbitary object.  This is what its usage looks like in Xaml:-

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <local:EnumToObjectConverter x:Key="Icons">
    <ResourceDictionary>
 <BitmapImage x:Key="Unknown" UriSource="/images/unknown.png" />
      <BitmapImage x:Key="WaitingToUpload" UriSource="/images/clock.png" />        
      <BitmapImage x:Key="Uploading"       UriSource="/images/upload.png" />        
      <BitmapImage x:Key="Uploaded"        UriSource="/images/tick.png" />        
      <BitmapImage x:Key="UploadFailed"    UriSource="/images/error.png" />        
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </local:EnumToObjectConverter>
</Grid.Resources>
```

This converter can be used when binding property of the enum type:-

```
 <Image Source="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource Icons}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I'll give it a whirl!

Answer (score 1):

Your `EnumImage` can be setup using `Image` with `DataTrigger`:

```
   <Image Tag="{Binding Gender}" Width="48" Height="48">
      <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Male">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Client_Male.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Female">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Client_Female.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Image.Style>
     </Image>
```

Source: [Displaying an image based on value in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967416/displaying-an-image-based-on-value-in-xaml#answer-17968216)