# Displaying an image based on value in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I display an image based on a value in XAML?

I have gender enumeration

```
[DataContract(Name = "Gender")]
public enum GenderEnum
{
    [EnumMember] NotSpecified,
    [EnumMember] Male,
    [EnumMember] Female,
}
```

At my Model class I have a property of that enumeration type called "Gender".
Now I want to display an image based on the value of "Gender" via the XAML side.

Comment: Inside a DataTemplate? Then you can use a trigger.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

XAML:

```
   <Image Tag="{Binding Gender}" Width="48" Height="48">
      <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="Male">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Client_Male.png"/>
                </DataTrigger >
                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Gender}" Value="Female">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Client_Female.png"/>
                </DataTrigger >
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Image.Style>
     </Image>
```

Comment: That's a much cleaner solution than the usual "you have to create a converter bla bla bla", thanks!

Comment: With binding specified in the `Tag` property of image all DataTrigger bindings in `<Image.Style>` should be referencing image's `Tag`, i.e. `Binding="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`