# WPF - Change string values of enum in combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, enums

I've got an enum which I use its values as choices in a combo box.

The enum is this:

```
public enum TimeSizeEnum
{
    TENTHSECONDS,
    SECONDS,
    MINUTES,
    HOURS
}
```

The way I'm binding the values to the combo box:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TimeSizeItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource TimerSizeConverter}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=TimeSize, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="5" MinWidth="100"></ComboBox>

public string[] TimeSizeItemsSource
{
    get
    {
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(TimeSizeEnum));
    }
}
```

I want that instead of `TENTHSECONDS`, I'll see `"Tenth of a second"` or instead of `SECONDS`, I'll see `"Seconds"`.

How can I achieve that? Is a value converter the best way to do it? But then it means I need to hard-code the strings I want?

Comment: an alternative to the answers is using a ValueConverter and the resource dictionary. Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787725/how-to-display-different-enum-icons-using-xaml-only

Comment: I use a Markup Extension for all my Enums, but they use the Description and Category Attributes much like a value converter does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx):

```
public enum TimeSizeEnum
{
    [Description("Tenths of a second")]
    TENTHSECONDS,

    [Description("Seconds")]
    SECONDS,

    [Description("Minutes")]
    MINUTES,

    [Description("Hours")]
    HOURS
}
```

You can then examine the `enum` value you're passed in a `ValueConverter`, read the description from the attribute, and display that:

```
public class TimeSizeEnumDescriptionValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var type = typeof(TimeSizeEnum);
        var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
        FieldInfo fi = type.GetField(name);
        var descriptionAttrib = (DescriptionAttribute)
            Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fi, typeof(DescriptionAttribute));

        return descriptionAttrib.Description;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

To apply the value converter to each enum value, you need to change the combo box's `ItemTemplate` to include the value converter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <test:TimeSizeEnumDescriptionValueConverter x:Key="converter" />
</Window.Resources>

<!-- ... -->

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TimeSizeItemsSource}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter
                Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Did you see I was binding the enum to the ItemsSource property of the Combobox? It means I get in the Value Converter the entire set of enum values (a string[]) and not a single value of the enum

Comment: I ran into the same issue when I was testing this solution, but it's easily solved - you need to add a `ContentPresenter` that includes the value converter into the combo box's `ItemTemplate` to apply it to each `enum` value. Updated my answer above.

Comment: Unless if it is for a very small app, I would strongly advise against using `DescriptionAttribute` for anything that's related to the UI. Not only it isn't localizable, but you may also want different descriptions to suite different UIs (short ones, longer ones, etc).

Answer (score 3):

You can put the attributes on your enum members like

```
public enum TimeSizeEnum
{
    [Description("Tenth of a second")]
    TENTHSECONDS,
    [Description("Seconds")]
    SECONDS,
}
```

and then you can write a converter which read and return these attributes from the value passed i.e in Convert method of your IValueConveter you can write

```
var enumtype = typeof(TimeSizeEnum);
var memInfo = enumtype.GetMember(value.ToString());
var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
    false);
var description = ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;

return description
```

Comment: Did you see I was binding the enum to the ItemsSource property of the Combobox? It means I get in the Value Converter the entire set of enum values (a string[]) and not a single value of the enum

Comment: Unless if it is for a very small app, I would strongly advise against using `DescriptionAttribute` for anything that's related to the UI. Not only it isn't localizable, but you may also want different descriptions to suite different UIs (short ones, longer ones, etc).