# Bind Image to ComboBox based on Object Enum Value

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding, valueconverter

I have a Character Class that has an property Gender that is an Enum. What I want my code to do is to switch images based on what gender my Character is(if the character is male = male image).

Where I am having the problem is how to correctly access and get this Enum value. You see, I am creating an ObservableCollection of type Character. I am then binding this collection to a ComboBox and then displaying the DisplayMemberPath via the ItemTemplate.

I believe I am doing all the binding right, but I am not accessing the Character Gender property correctly in my value converter.

**The XAML:** Referencing the Converter && ComboBox

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ImageViaGenderTest_2014"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="1004.932">
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:GenderToIconFilenameConverter x:Key="IconConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>


 <ComboBox x:Name="Character_ComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328" Height="25">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="50" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Width="50" Text="{Binding Level}"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Gender, Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

**The Observable Collection Setup in MainWindow**

```
  public ObservableCollection<Character> squad_members = new ObservableCollection<Character>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        squad_members.Add(new Character() { Name = "john_snow_knows_nothing", Level = 8,  _Gender = Gender.Male});
        squad_members.Add(new Character() { Name = "Ygritt_gets_wrecked", Level = 4,  _Gender = Gender.Female});

        Binding comboBinding = new Binding();
        comboBinding.Source = squad_members;

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(Character_ComboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, comboBinding);
    }
```

**The Custom Value Converter Class(Where I think I'm referencing the Gender Enum incorrectly) ERROR AREA:**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Gender), typeof(Image))]
public class GenderToIconFilenameConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
            switch ((Gender)value)
            {
                case Gender.Female:
                    return "character1.jpg";
                case Gender.Male:
                    return "character2.jpg";
                default:
                    return null;
            }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**Character Class:**

```
public class Character 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public Gender _Gender { get; set; }
}
```

**Gender Enum:**

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male, Female
}
```

Am i referencing my Character Gender enum incorrectly? Or is there something else I forgot?
I also got help from this question:
[Bind Icon depending on Enum in WPF Treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786792/bind-icon-depending-on-enum-in-wpf-treeview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a solution in pure xaml

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="Character_ComboBox"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="328"
              Height="25">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="50"
                               Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Width="50"
                               Text="{Binding Level}" />
                    <Image x:Name="gender" />
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding _Gender}"
                                 Value="Female">
                        <Setter Property="Source"
                                TargetName="gender"
                                Value="character1.jpg" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding _Gender}"
                                 Value="Male">
                        <Setter Property="Source"
                                TargetName="gender"
                                Value="character2.jpg" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

this approach do not require any converter and this is more beneficial when you have less options.

What is happening here is that we have specified DataTrigger on the template and we check the value of the Gender property and when it meet certain criteria we set the image source accordingly.

Comment: this works, but the DataTrigger Binding must be <DataTrigger Binding = "{Binding _Gender}">. Emphasis on "_Gender" instead of "Gender". Thanks for the help!